# недопустимый envelope-from в exim

Tags: exim

Установил exim на centos 6, он в базовой конфигурации, изменил только способ авторизации юзеров на passwd файл:

```
login:
driver = plaintext
public_name = LOGIN
server_prompts = "Username:: : Password::"
server_set_id = $auth1
server_condition = "${if exists{/etc/exim/passwd}{${lookup{$1}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}\
{${if crypteq{$auth2}{\\\{md5\\\}${extract{1}{:}{$value}{$value}fail}} {true}{false} }}}}}"
```

логин это полный email, т.е. user@domain.ru

отправляю письмо и вижу такие заголовки:

```
Return-Path: "noreply@domain.ru"@mx.domain.ru
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront7j.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1497685386
Authentication-Results: mxfront7j.mail.yandex.net; dkim=pass header.i=@domain.ru
X-Yandex-Spam: 4
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=domain.ru; s=dkim; h=Sender:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:
    MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:From:To:Date:Reply-To:Cc:Content-ID:
    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=p0SNRwx0/U6/74oIfNiicXPYOf7JujdEfLl4DGWrp80=; b=FgUdR2zgRykXn+FRhc3m9AkgGA
    kBvtwhfemijDQo9mW4sz33oRQjCZXr80GtjfAqVJKVrLKmHdIfChYM73x+hdd3ClzDgT+o9dlAAil
    dgqNOmiHaOsIvQxVg1olW9wQpqaqMYTjc53QIPv6rYJSHk07mJnH9fw2MEc4fhaipdrE=;
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (helo=www.domain.ru)
    by mx.domain.ru with esmtpa (Exim 4.89)
    (envelope-from <"noreply@domain.ru"@mx.domain.ru>)
    id 1dM8Nu-0000ip-32
    for user@yandex.ru; Sat, 17 Jun 2017 10:43:06 +0300

www.domain.ru - хостнейм
domain.ru - сам домен
mx.domain.ru - почтовый сервер(MX запись в DNS)
user@yandex.ru - получатель
```

в заголовка return-path и envelope-from подставлены автоматом самим exim'ом, и поставлен неверно, я так понимаю он их формирует как логин@хостнейм(у меня логин это полный email с хостом), из-за этого письма попадают сразу в спам, а некоторые почтовики их вообще не принимают.

подскажите, как исправить, немогу нигде найти инфы по решению этой проблеммы...

Comment: вообще эту информацию указывает программа, формирующая сообщение, а не принявший сообщение smtp-сервер.

Comment: исправил пост по замечаниям...
Скрипт отправки(phpmailer) эти данные не добавляем.
При попытке в скрипте напрямую задать эти заголовки, он игнорируются и переписываются на те что выше.

Comment: так что, определились с тем, какая программа формирует сообщения и подставляет смущающую вас информацию?

Comment: попробуйте от имени вашего пользователя выполнить команду (подставив актуальные адреса): `$ echo -e 'subject: test\n\ntest body' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f '<noreply@domain.ru>' user@yandex.ru` и посмотрите, что будет указана во from, return-path и envelope-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html) на значение поля `envelope from` и заголовков `from:` и `return-path:` влияют (как минимум) три конфигурационных параметра:

- `local_from_check` (по умолчанию `true`)
- `local_sender_retain` (по умолчанию `false`)
- `untrusted_set_sender` (по умолчанию пусто)

в идущей с дистрибутивом *debian gnu/linux* конфигурации в файле `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options` есть такие строки:

```
.ifndef MAIN_FORCE_SENDER
local_from_check = false
local_sender_retain = true
untrusted_set_sender = *
.endif
```

и, так как параметр `MAIN_FORCE_SENDER` по умолчанию не определён, три вышеупомянутых параметра переопределяются, что позволяет (по умолчанию) программе, формирующей сообщение, указывать произвольный обратный адрес. например, так:

```
$ echo -e 'subject: test\n\ntest body' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f noreply@domain.ru user@yandex.ru
```

и `noreply@domain.ru` попадает и в `envelope from`, и в заголовки `from:` и `return-path:`

---

судя по содержимому файла `etc/exim/exim.conf` из пакета `https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/exim-4.89-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`, эти три вышеупомянутых параметра не переопределены (они не встречаются в файле).

поэтому, если вы хотите, чтобы информация об отправителе, передаваемая программой, формирующей сообщения, принималась программой *exim* во внимание (а не игнорировалась), попробуйте добавить те же строки, что и в *debian-овском* конифигурационном файле:

```
local_from_check = false
local_sender_retain = true
untrusted_set_sender = *
```

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло.