# Как в EXIM разрешить подмену адреса?

Tags: vps, centos7, exim, vesta, exim4

Помогите разобраться. Есть VPS/Centos7. Для работы с почтой стоит exim4. Есть задача. Надо отправить 300 писем разным адресатам по SMTP.

Для отправления есть один пользователь user@domain.com но отправить письма надо так чтобы в заголовках письма при каждом отправлении адрес отправителя менялся с user@domain.com на любой другой например user1@, user2@, user3@.

Не хочу создавать кучу аккаунтов. Хочу все с одного делать но с подменой.

Comment: непонятно, при чём тут mta. замените поле from в mua на то, что требуется.

Comment: мне чтобы это было автоматически, надо отправить 200 писем на разные адреса. Типо рассылка. В MTA я вношу адреса отправителей они по шаблону user1@, user2@, user3@ итд. Я бы мог внести их в ручную на VPS т.е. создать всех отправителей. Но мне так не охота )

Comment: какое ко всему этому имеют а) получатели; б) какие-то шаблоны; в) какая-то там автоматизация (чего???). изложите, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос яснее, нажав [edit].

Comment: отредактировал, может так яснее, посмотрите

Comment: подставлять нужное в заголовок from надо в вашем mua. например: `$ echo "test message" | mail -r "user$((RANDOM%3+1))domain.com" -s "test" кому@нибу.дь`

Comment: Я понять не могу куда этот код вставлять ((

Comment: Я тут еще наткнулся на Ваш комментарий https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680356/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-envelope-from-%D0%B2-exim/680832#680832

Comment: 1. это был пример команды для оболочки. 2. когда (и если) возникнут описанные в том вопросе проблемы — прочитайте и примите ответ к сведению.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Разобрался.